# How can I check whether a field exists or not in MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have created some documents and managed to make some simple queries but I can't create a query that would find documents where a field just exists.

For example suppose this is a document:

```
{  "profile_sidebar_border_color" : "D9B17E" , 
   "name" : "???? ???????" , "default_profile" : false , 
   "show_all_inline_media" : true , "otherInfo":["text":"sometext", "value":123]}
```

Now I want a query that will bring all the documents where the text in `otherInfo` has something in it.

If there is no text, then the `otherInfo` will just be like that: `"otherInfo":[]`

So I want to check the existence of the `text` field in `otherInfo`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use the `$exists` operator in combination with the `.` notation. The bare query in the mongo-shell should look like this:

```
db.yourcollection.find({ 'otherInfo.text' : { '$exists' : true }})
```

And a test case in Java could look like this:

```
    BasicDBObject dbo = new BasicDBObject();
    dbo.put("name", "first");
    collection.insert(dbo);

    dbo.put("_id", null);
    dbo.put("name", "second");
    dbo.put("otherInfo", new BasicDBObject("text", "sometext"));
    collection.insert(dbo);

    DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("otherInfo.text", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true));
    DBCursor result = collection.find(query);
    System.out.println(result.size());
    System.out.println(result.iterator().next());
```

Output:

```
1
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "4f809e72764d280cf6ee6099"} , "name" : "second" , "otherInfo" : { "text" : "sometext"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use:

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.exists;

Document doc = (Document) mongoCollection.find(exists("otherInfo")).first();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `com.mongodb.QueryBuilder` class to build a query provided in Matt's answer:

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilder.start("otherInfo.text").exists(true);
DBObject query = queryBuilder.get();
DBCursor dbCursor = collection.find(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the in query filter out all elements with the text value see below.

```
db.things.find({otherInfo:{$in: [text]}});

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("otherInfo", new BasicDBObject("$in", "[text]"));
var result = db.find(query);
```