# mongodb filter in multi level subdocument?

Tags: mongodb

This is my mongodb table design

```js
  "_id" : ObjectId("5368e65ae6aa265432000002"),
"accounts" : {},
"contacts" : {
    "1" : {
        "accounts" : {
            "user1" : "data",
            "user3" : "data"
        }
    },
    "2" : {
        "accounts" : {
            "user2" : "data",
            "user5" : "data",
        }
    },
    "3" : {
        "accounts" : {
            "user4" : "data"
            "user7" : "data",
        }
    }
},
```

My problem is how to check the user is already associated with any of accounts object or not.

for example i have the data like user1,user2. i want to check whether the key is already added or not...

Comment: Don't put your dynamic data (like IDs) in key names.  As you're seeing, it gives you no end of troubles.

Answer (score 0):

How to check whether a field exists or not in MongoDB you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057651/how-can-i-check-whether-a-field-exists-or-not-in-mongodb).

In your case:

```
db.yourcollectionname.find({"contacts.1.accounts.user1": { $exists : true }})
```

But unfortunately I can not answer , how to check all ids (1,2,3) at the one query

Comment: Probably db.yourcollectionname.find($or:[{"contacts.1.accounts.user1": { $exists : true }},{"contacts.2.accounts.user1": { $exists : true }},{"contacts.3.accounts.user1": { $exists : true }}]). But it looks really ugly. It seems design of db structure doesn't fit to data usage pattern. It may make sense to think of restructure.

Comment: @balaphp The better answer is you need to change the structure of your data. Sub-documents like you have require absolute paths as you were shown. You need your contacts actually be an array, and the "user" keys need to be values instead. That way you can simply compare.