# Updating pre-existing documents in mongoDB java driver when you've changed document structure

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, mongo-java-driver

I've got a database of playerdata that has some pre-existing fields from previous versions of the program. Example out-dated document:

```
{
   "playername": "foo"
}
```

but a player document generated under the new version would look like this:

```
{
   "playername": "bar",
   "playercurrency": 20
}
```

the issue is that if I try to query `playercurrency` on `foo` I get a NullPointerException because `playercurrency` doesn't exist for `foo`. I want to add the `playercurrency` field to `foo` without disturbing any other data that could be stored in `foo`. I've tried some code using `$exists` Example:

```
players.updateOne(new Document("playername", "foo"), new Document("$exists", new Document("playername", "")));
players.updateOne(new Document("playername", "foo"), new Document("$exists", new Document("playercurrency", 20)));
```

My thought is that it updates only `playercurrency` because it doesn't exist and it would leave `playername` alone becuase it exists. I might be using exists horribly wrong, and if so please do let me know because this is one of my first MongoDB projects and I would like to learn as much as I possibly can.

Comment: Does pre-existing fields are like this : [{"playername": "foo"},{"playername": "bar"},{"playername": "tar"}]. Just asking...

Comment: I don't understand your question... I guess to clarify `foo` and `bar` are their own documents, each has different fields, because one was generated on an old version and the other was generated on the newer version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I know that it is normally frowned upon on answering your own question, but nobody really posted what I ended up doing I would like to take this time to thank [@Mark Watson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/524124/mark-watson) for answering and ultimately guiding me to finding my answer.

Since checking if a certain field is `null` doesn't work in the MongoDB Java Driver I needed to find a different way to know when something is primed for an update. So after a little bit of research I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057651/how-can-i-check-whether-a-field-exists-or-not-in-mongodb) which helped me come up with this code:

```
private static void updateValue(final String name, final Object defaultValue, final UUID key) {
        if (!exists(name, key)) {
            FindIterable iterable = players.find(new Document("_id", key));

            iterable.forEach(new Block<Document>() {

                @Override
                public void apply(Document document) {
                    players.updateOne(new Document("_id", key), new Document("$set", new Document(name, defaultValue)));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private static boolean exists(String name, UUID key) {
        Document query = new Document(name, new Document("$exists", true)).append("_id", key);

        return players.count(query) == 1;
    }
```

Obviously this is a little specialized to what I wanted to do, but with little revisions it can be easliy changed to work with anything you might need. Make sure to replace `players` with your Collection object.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to do this with java? Whenever I add a new field that I want to be required I just use the command line to migrate all existing documents. This will loop through all players that don't have a playercurrency and set it to 0 (change to whatever default you want):

`db.players.find({playercurrency:null}).forEach(function(player) {
    player.playercurrency = 0; // or whatever default value
    db.players.save(player);
});`

This will result in you having the following documents:

`{
    "playername" : "foo",
    "playercurrency" : 0
}`

`{
    "playername" : "bar",
    "playercurrency" : 20
}`

Comment: I will definitely look into that, thank you for the response!