# Mongoose retrieve documents if object keys exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema called Users :

```
let UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
firstname: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
},
lastname: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
},
houses: {
  type: Map,
  of: Array,
  required:[true,"No Units Detected"]
},
gender: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
},
email: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
  unique: true,
  lowercase: true,
  validate: (value) => {
    return validator.isEmail(value);
  },

},
```

Which leads to documents being saved as :
Document 1:

```
    {
       firstname:"user1",
       lastname:"user",
       gender:"male",
       email:"user@users.com",
       houses: {
          "New York" : ['house1','house2']
          "Florida"  :  ['house1','house2']
      }
     }
```

Document 2:

```
    {
       firstname:"user2",
       lastname:"user",
       gender:"female",
       email:"user2@users.com",
       houses: {
          "Florida"  :  ['house1']
          "Texas"    : ['house1']
      }
     }
```

the purpose of the schemas is to list the houses of each user even if the user has multiple houses in multiple states.
My question is : Is there any query I could use to list the users in a certain state (which is a key inside an object)
for example :
Query for texas would return User 2 only , query for Florida would return user 1 and user 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check whether a field exists or not in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057651/how-can-i-check-whether-a-field-exists-or-not-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1: Use `$exist`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "houses.Texas": { $exists: true }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RuBJwaLSYNG)

---

Method 2: Use `$objectToArray`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $ne: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: { $objectToArray: "$houses" },
              as: "h",
              cond: { $eq: [ "$$h.k", "Texas" ] }
            }
          },
          []
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kC6xlINHEIl)